# Datatables row sum is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I have a table that data is used MySQL, PHP, Datatables in Codeigniter frame work. And I am trying to get the row sum of the table.

I used the following code fragments.

### To get sum (Relevant Parts Only)

```
<th><input id="selectAll" type="checkbox" /></th>

<td><input class="selected" type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?= $value->payback_id ?>" /></td>

<tfoot>
     <tr class="" style="background-color: #cc99ff !important;">
          <td colspan="<?= $type ? 5 : 6 ?>">Total</td>
          <td id="total_amount"  class="text-right" ></td>
          <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
```

```
<script>
 $('#selectAll').change(function(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            $(".selected").prop("checked", true)
            $('.amount').map((key,ele) => {
                total += parseFloat(ele.value.replaceAll(",",""))
            })
            showForm()
            
        } else {
            total = 0
            $(".selected").prop("checked", false)
            hideForm()
        }
        $('#total_amount').text(numberWithCommas(total.toFixed(2)))
    })
</script>
```

### Output

Got 0.00 for the row sum. What may be going wrong ? Can anyone help ?

Required fields of the MySQL table as follows :

```
id, imprest_salary_id, imprest_request_id, payment_type, amount, created_by, updated_by, created_at, updated_at
```

Comment: @ Vickel. Ok. I Edited.

Comment: remove `total = 0` from the else clause and place befor the `if else` block, otherwise total in the `if clause` is undefined

Comment: @ Vickel. Changed. But got the same result 0.00

Comment: how does a typical `ele.value` look like?